# Как раскодировать xml в кодировке 1251

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

Выдает ошибку:

> System.Xml.XmlException: "System does not support 'windows-1251' encoding.

Как раскодировать?

```
string URLXml = "http://сайт.ru/file.xml";

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URLXml);

while (reader.Read())
{}
```

Comment: Добавьте подробностей. Что используете: .NET Framework или .NET Core? И какой версии? Может у вас специфическое окружение, наподобие Unity и т. п. Чем больше опишите, тем больше шанс получить решение проблемы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov использую .Net Core, версия 3.1.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В отличие от обычного .NET Framework, в котором изначально поддерживается большое количество кодировок, в .NET Core по умолчанию доступны лишь несколько базовых.

Вся информация описана в документации: [CodePagesEncodingProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider?view=netcore-3.1).

- Добавьте в проект ссылку на сборку System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll.
- Получите объект CodePagesEncodingProvider из статического свойства CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.
- Передайте объект CodePagesEncodingProvider методу Encoding.RegisterProvider.

Фактически, в код нужно добавить одну строку:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ошибка пропала, но появилась другая, которую исправил так.                              `XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 1024; `

Answer (score 0):

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать LINQ to XML API.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string Url = @"http://сайт.ru/file.xml";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Url);
}
```

Comment: Точно такая же ошибка с кодировкой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поделитесь реальным URL. Я смогу воспроизвести на моей стороне.